# What does a medical certificate look like?

Tags: faa-regulations, medical, pilot-certification

I can't find any images of a medical certificate other than the old version that was combined with the student pilot certificate. What do new medical certificates look like?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a sample from this website: [sample medical certificate](https://www.boldmethod.com/learn-to-fly/regulations/FAA-COVID-19-medical-certificate-expiration-policy/)

[image]